# adding months properly in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to add 15 months to an existing date. However the result is not proper end of month which is expected from using %m+% in lubridate.

```
> as.Date("2018-04-30") %m+% months(15)
[1] "2019-07-30"
```

Comment: Wrong expectation. `%m+%` does **not** give you the end of the month -- it ensures you don't **exceed** the end of the month, like getting February 31 or something (I think this is the example in the docs)

Comment: @r2evans and @ duckmayr wow I did not know that. i indeed had wrong expectation. I will  add additional arguments that will make it end of month as well.

Comment: `rollback(as.Date("2018-04-30") %m+% months(15+1))` might be what you want (the `+1` is just to demonstrate going one month *further*, and `rollback` is new).

Comment: have a look at `lubridate::ceiling_date(x, unit = "months")` to return the end of the month

Comment: @Edo, that produces `"2019-08-01"`, not what I'm inferring is the intended `"2019-07-31"`. (Though using `ceiling_date(...) - 1` works.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%m+%` simply adds the months, at no point is there an assumption that it will maintain the "last day of the month" status. As @duckmayr succinctly stated, it protects against exceeding the end of the month, but I believe it should not be a safe assumption to *infer* it should push out accordingly.

Alternatives:

```r
rollback(as.Date("2018-04-30") %m+% months(15+1))
# [1] "2019-07-31"

ceiling_date(as.Date("2018-04-30") %m+% months(15), unit="month") - 1
# [1] "2019-07-31"

ceiling_date(as.Date("2018-04-30") %m+% months(15), unit="month") %m+% days(-1)
# [1] "2019-07-31"
```

And perhaps some further combinations.

Comment: x<-x  %m+% months(15) 
  day(x)<-days_in_month(x)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `yearmon` class in the zoo package. I think it is better thought out for this purpose than the `lubridate` functions appear to be. You would not need to separately calculate the extra days. Notice that additon of months needs to be in years so divide the months by 12. The `frac`=1 as argument to  `as.Date.yearmon` returns the last day of the month:

```
library(zoo)
as.Date( as.yearmon( as.Date("2018-04-30") ) +15 , frac=1)
[1] "2033-04-30"    Wrong!!!
# Divided months by 12
as.Date( as.yearmon( as.Date("2018-04-30") ) +15/12 , frac=1)
[1] "2019-07-31"   Success
```